# Text disappearing after html page load

Tags: jquery, html, css

After my page loads my text disappears and I am having trouble determining why. (I am coming in after-the-fact and did not write the site)

http://www.woodgroupfs.com/index2.html The white text on top of the header image shows up, like it is supposed to and then it gets removed.

Any ideas?

Comment: What white text disappears? I don't see anything disappearing.

Comment: This is a screen shot of it before it disappears: http://www.woodgroupfs.com/img/screenshot.jpg and this is the code that should display it: <div id="headerBackground">
          <div id="headerPhrase">Rotating Equipment Repair<br>
            Field Services, Field Machining
        </div>
            <div id="headerImages">
             <div id="headerServices">
            <img src="images/headers/index2.png" alt="Field Services and Millwright Services">
       </div>       
          </div>
          </div>

Comment: By my look, there is no element there in the code, and it doesn't appear to be a part of the image.

Comment: After load and on inspect element the original code is not there, you are correct. Which is part of my puzzlement. I can't figure out what is removing it. And it should sit on top of the image so you are also right on that count, it isn't part of the image. This is the css for it: #headerPhrase {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  top:275px;
   font: 700 normal 22px/150% "camingodos-web-1","camingodos-web-2",Arial,Tahoma,sans-serif;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 10;
  
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white text that is disappearing in the header is in an element with id `#headerPhrase`. On line 156 of your scripts.js:

```
$('#headerPhrase').remove();
```

is completely removing it from the page.

I guess because some images have the white text burned into them, that's why it is happening, so it might not be as simple as just removing this line.

Comment: Awesome..Redoing headers is not a problem but not being able to get the text to show up was. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you disable JavaScript and reload the page, the text appears... so I suggest you have a look at all the JavaScript running on your page and find what is removing it.

Edit: after looking through your JavaScripts, I saw this line in your script.js:

```
$('#headerPhrase').remove();
```

That'd be the culprit...

Answer (score 1):

script.js line 156 = `$('#headerPhrase').remove();`

In Firebug: IF I remove this line all works fine!